# JQuery - Select tag issue with Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

i'm having an issue with JQuery using chrome.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="selectInputContainer" id="selectmaerkeContainer" onClick="selectOption('maerke');">
     <span class="selectValue"></span>
     <select name="bilmaerke" class="selectInput" id="selectmaerke">
         <option value="">Alle</option>
         <?php echo $bilMaerkeOptionOutput; ?>
      </select>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
function selectOption(selectId){
    optionVar = $("#select" + selectId + "Container").find("select option:selected").text();
    $("#select" + selectId + "Container").find('.selectValue').text(optionVar);
}
```

Everything works in Safari but not Chrome or Opera so i guess it's my code that's wrong.
PS. i'm new at JQuery, be nice to me! :)

Comment: There doesn't really seem to be anything obvious that would make that code *not* work in chrome, but work in Safari? They both use webkit, so it seems strange. Did you open the console and check for errors?

Comment: Are you defining that function before it's being used? Works ok in Chrome for me: http://jsfiddle.net/MtAda/

Comment: The only thing I can spot is `onClick` should be all lowercase, `onclick`, but it usually works anyway ?

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console: 
"event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

Comment: Here's a crazy idea, use proper event handlers, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/MtAda/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you binding the event handler to the wrapping div click? Can be an event propagation issue.

I think it's better to bind the select `change` event like:

```
<div class="selectInputContainer" id="selectmaerkeContainer" > <span class="selectValue"></span>

    <select name="bilmaerke" class="selectInput" id="selectmaerke" onchange="selectOption('maerke');">
        <option value="">Alle</option>
        <option value="x">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rAWfJ/

Comment: Thank you! I should just use on change instead of onclick, seems like Safari was the only one accepting onclick.